# reduce javascript code when using the map function

Tags: javascript, dictionary, lodash

I want to iterate over an array and do something to each of the element

```
d = d.map(function(d){
    return _.omit(d, 'password');
})

d = d.map(function(d){
    return d.toString();
})
```

these functions are working correctly.  But after it showed up too many times the code becomes really messy.

So I was wondering if there's easier ways to do what I want to do? I am hoping to reduce the code to one line only using bind or apply keywords or some modules (maybe lodash or underscore..).  Is this possible?

Comment: can you tell what actually you doing here, I mean problem.

Comment: *"But after it showed up too many times the code becomes really messy."* Do you mean you are calling the same code over and over again? Create a function!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using a version of JavaScript that supports [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), you could use those:

```
d = d.map((d) => _.omit(d, 'password'));
```

Or if you're repeating the same code a lot, you can make helper functions:

```
function removePasswords(d) {
    return d.map(function (d) {
        return _.omit(d, 'password');
    });
}

d = removePasswords(d);
```

If you're performing a lot of `map`s one after the other, you can combine their contents

```
d = d.map(function(d) {
    return _.omit(d, 'password').toString();
});
```

Otherwise, I don't think it's going to get much shorter than what you already have. It's already pretty short.

You may want to look into using [Coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/) if you feel that JavaScript is too verbose:

```
d = d.map (d) -> _.omit(d, 'password')
```

Comment: d = d.map( (d) => _.omit(d, 'secret') ); mine says SyntaxError: Unexpected token >.. @@

Comment: @ChandlerLee Then that most likely means you're not using a version of JS that supports arrow functions. Most browsers don't yet, but you can use [traceur compiler](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler) to compile ES6 into browser-friendly JavaScript.